# Display drop-down list items over container, without vertical scrollbar?

Tags: css, angularjs, drop-down-menu, z-order

Created a drop down navigation block which can be clicked or hovered, at which point a list of sub-items would drop down, each of which can also be clicked.

This worked fine until trying to use it in a more complicated intranet framework (LumApps, which relies heavily on AngularJS). When placed in an HTML widget, the bottom of the sub-item list is cut off and vertical scrollbar is displayed within the widget.

Resting state and current hover state:
[image: Click or Hover resting state, hover state]

Have tried many things, including z-order and overflow settings, but can't seem to find what's preventing the full list of sub-items from being displayed over the container (and anything else) underneath.

How hover state should appear:
[image: Proper hover state behavior]

My code at its essentials:

```
<style type="text/css">
.nav {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    list-style:none;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color:#24135f;
    color:#ffffff;
    width: 30%;
    padding: 1%;
}
.nav a {
    display:block;
    color:#ffffff;
    height: 100%;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.nav:hover .nav-dropdown {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:49px;
    text-transform: none;
}
.nav-dropdown {
    display:none;
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    background:#665a8f;
}
.nav-dropdown a {
    padding:10px 15px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#ffffff;
}
.nav-dropdown li:hover a {
    background:#24135f;
}
</style>
 <ul class="nav">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Click or Hover</a>
        <ul class="nav-dropdown">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Item 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Item 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Item 3</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Item 4</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Any idea how to obtain the desired behavior within the aforementioned framework?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you already try with  overflow:visible; in you navbar?

Comment: Deleted answer as not useful _  You may want to add a sentence explaining about the deep nesting of the widget and about the involvement of angular _ Also upvoted _ Hope you get more useful advice / solution soon ; )

Comment: @SaHagin yes, `overflow:visible` and `z-order` without luck

Comment: I've been thinking about this a bit more.... Came up with two things that might be worth checking out: 1) you may have already done this, but have you gone through any attributes that might be in the styling of the (multiple) parent divs you mentioned? both `.` and `#`  _ 2) might be more useful: `nav` is such a common class name and may even be used by angular... would the changes you want occur if you replaced `nav` with a less common class name? Probably nothing @pseudonymo _ I'm just thinking out loud... ; )